# Laravel 5.3 Loop error

Tags: for-loop, laravel-5.3

Hi Im trying to loop a calendar months and years but My loop stops at the very first iteration at the index function Can you help me?

Index Function:

```
public function index()
{
$users = DB::table('users')->where('roles_id', '2')->get();

  date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Hong_Kong");

  for ($iterateYear = 2017; $iterateYear < 2018; $iterateYear++) {
    for ($iterateMonth = 1; $iterateMonth <= 12; $iterateMonth++) {

      /* Set the date */
      $date = strtotime(sprintf('%s-%s-01', $iterateYear, $iterateMonth));
      return $this->renderCalenderMonth($date);

    }
  }

    return view('transaction.index', [
      'users' => $users
    ]);
}
```

RenderCalendarMonth function:

public function renderCalenderMonth($date) {

```
  // $date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));
  $NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS = 37;

  $day = date('d', $date);
  $month = date('m', $date);
  $year = date('Y', $date);

  $firstDay = mktime(0,0,0,$month, 1, $year);
  $title = strftime('%B', $firstDay);
  $dayOfWeek = date('D', $firstDay);
  $daysInMonth = cal_days_in_month(0, $month, $year);
  /* Get the name of the week days */
  $timestamp = strtotime('next Sunday');
  $weekDays = [];

  for($i = 0; $i < $NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS; $i++) {
      $weekDays[] = strftime('%a', $timestamp);
      $timestamp = strtotime('+1 day', $timestamp);
  }
  $blank = date('w', strtotime("{$year}-{$month}-01"));

  $divid = $title.$year;

  return view('transaction.index', [
    'date' => $date,
    'day' => $day,
    'month' => $month,
    'year' => $year,
    'firstDay' => $firstDay,
    'title' => $title,
    'dayOfWeek' => $dayOfWeek,
    'daysInMonth' => $daysInMonth,
    'timestamp' => $timestamp,
    'weekDays' => $weekDays,
    'blank' => $blank,
    'divid' => $divid,
    'NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS' => $NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS
  ]);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a return statement in your loop, so what you are doing is you are going into renderCalenderMonth then return the generated view. then leave the loop .If you want to continuously return values from a loop use the php yield keyword.

Comment: where should I then pass the generator? At the views?

Comment: What I would do is something like this:

Comment: What is would do is something like this: `$months = [];  $months[] = $this->renderCalenderMonth($date); ` now you have an array of months, then you can iterate it and do whatever you wanna do with each month

Comment: I am able to store the value in an array. And I can now display the values. However I am having a hard time in looping each value for my function. Are you familiar with Laravel 5.3?

Comment: Maybe if you can explain what exactly you are trying to do,we can get a clearer picture and a better answer might come up.For example your nested for loops are confusing because they only iterate once, from 2017 to 2018 which means you do not need the parent loop.Only the child loop which loops over 12 months.Please give the full spec then we can take it from there.

Comment: What I wanted to do with the array for months and year. I want to generate a calendar table for each month in a year. Each table will be inserted in a div for tab navigation purposes. Here is my git repo https://github.com/chuaquino/collab.git